# Why does Antlr default to certain alternatives over others?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr4

I am using the antlr4 plugin for IntelliJ to create a grammar for a project I'm working on.  In the process of learning how to use antlr, I took a look at Github user shmatov's simple antlr4 calculator shown below.

```
grammar Calculator;
INT    : [0-9]+;
DOUBLE : [0-9]+'.'[0-9]+;
PI     : 'pi';
E      : 'e';
POW    : '^';
NL     : '\n';
WS     : [ \t\r]+ -> skip;
ID     : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;

PLUS  : '+';
EQUAL : '=';
MINUS : '-';
MULT  : '*';
DIV   : '/';
LPAR  : '(';
RPAR  : ')';

input
    : plusOrMinus NL? EOF # Calculate
    ;

plusOrMinus 
    : plusOrMinus PLUS multOrDiv  # Plus
    | plusOrMinus MINUS multOrDiv # Minus
    | multOrDiv                   # ToMultOrDiv
    ;

multOrDiv
    : multOrDiv MULT pow # Multiplication
    | multOrDiv DIV pow  # Division
    | pow                # ToPow
    ;

pow
    : unaryMinus (POW pow)? # Power
    ;

unaryMinus
    : MINUS unaryMinus # ChangeSign
    | atom             # ToAtom
    ;

atom
    : PI                    # ConstantPI
    | E                     # ConstantE
    | DOUBLE                # Double
    | INT                   # Int
    | ID                    # Variable
    | LPAR plusOrMinus RPAR # Braces
    ;
```

Interestingly, when a single number is entered, such as the integer '5', the resulting parse tree shows that the # Plus and # Multiplication labels are run.  This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  There are no `+` or `*` operators in the input.  I've uploaded an image of the parse tree below to give a better idea of what I'm talking about.

[image: Parse tree]

It seems that antlr just defaults to whatever the first alternative in the rule is, but wouldn't it make more sense for the calculator to take the straight path through labels `# Calculate -> # ToMultOrDiv -> # ToPow -> # ToAtom -> # Int`?  How does it even go through # Plus and # Multiplication without the right operators?

Comment: FYI, opened an issue for this: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good observation! I'm guessing the ANTLR plugin doesn't display the labels correctly. You could open an issue here: https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/issues (EDIT, opened an issue myself: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2222)

When you let the input `"5"` go through a listener, you will see the correct path is displayed:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class Main {

    static class Listener extends CalculatorBaseListener {

        @Override
        public void enterCalculate(CalculatorParser.CalculateContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Calculate");
        }

        @Override
        public void enterToMultOrDiv(CalculatorParser.ToMultOrDivContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("ToMultOrDiv");
        }

        @Override
        public void enterToPow(CalculatorParser.ToPowContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("ToPow");
        }

        @Override
        public void enterPower(CalculatorParser.PowerContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Power");
        }

        @Override
        public void enterToAtom(CalculatorParser.ToAtomContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("ToAtom");
        }

        @Override
        public void enterInt(CalculatorParser.IntContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Int");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculatorLexer lexer = new CalculatorLexer(CharStreams.fromString("5"));
        CalculatorParser parser = new CalculatorParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new Listener(), parser.input());
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
Calculate
ToMultOrDiv
ToPow
Power
ToAtom
Int
```